# Creating a python loop where the input is a random number

Tags: python, loops, hash, bcrypt

This is my code so far:

```
    import bcrypt
    import random

    def PRG():
        print(random.randint(1,100000))

    For i in range(1,3):
        print(bcrypt.gensalt(PRG()))
```

Which gives the output:

```
    77494
    $2a$04$2tpKWJxtsBAK1FYdM.6MSe
    87956
    $2a$04$4ag2YmOBFSFRR3Lu0RgQ8.
```

I'm just trying to make a loop that gives a bunch of salts based on what random number PRG() outputs. I'm not sure if the hash is the hash of the number output by PRG() because bcrypt output isn't fixed, and if someone could tell me how to remove the numeric output I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: in order to remove the numeric output return from PRG instead of printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `print(random.randint(1,100000))` with `return random.randint(1,100000)`